# I want to control 10 dynamixel motors using ROS Python. I am succeeding up to 6 motors at a time but not all

Tags: dynamixel

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to control 10 Dynamixel motors using ROS PYTHON, I am succeeded  to control 6 motors at a time. But while not all 10. What should i do to move them using my slider control program, As i started my executing  my code ALL MOTORS ARE MOVING IN RANDOM DIRECTION

HERE IS MY CODE

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import time
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Float64
from Tkinter import *

rospy.init_node('adi', anonymous=True)
pub1 = rospy.Publisher('/joint1/command', Float64, queue_size=10)
.
.
.
pub10 = rospy.Publisher('/joint10/command', Float64, queue_size=10)

def a():
    pub1.publish(3)   # It sets the motor to center position
.
.
.
.
    pub10.publish(3)
    print  w1.get(), w2.get() , w3.get(), w4.get() , w5.get() , w6.get() , w7.get() , w8.get() , w9.get() , w10.get() 
    pub1.publish(w1.get()*0.01)
    .
.
.
.
         pub10.publish(w10.get()*0.01)


master = Tk()
master.title("ADI")
w1 = Scale(master, from_=-360, to=360, orient=HORIZONTAL,length=300)
w1.pack()
.
.
.
w10 = Scale(master, from_=-360, to=360, orient=HORIZONTAL,length=300)
w10.pack()
Button(master, text='Move', command=a).pack()
a()
master.mainloop()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263114/i-want-to-control-10-dynamixel-motors-using-ros-python.-i-am-succeeding-up-to-6-motors-at-a-time-but-not-all/) by [ADIROSGAZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/30615/adirosgaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-06-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-03**:
Could it be related to the fact that your `shift` or `caps-lock` keys seem to be stuck?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-06-03**:
I've fixed your question title. Please don't use ALL CAPS for titles; it's the online equivalent of shouting and is considered rude on this forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used 2 different files a1.py & a2.py to write 2 different functions of five arguments (for each motor) in each py file.   i called those functions from other py file to communicate to the motors at a time. I succeeded for my operation what i want to do.

---

Originally posted by [ADIROSGAZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/30615/adirosgaz/) with karma: 31 on 2018-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0